# Encrypting using RSA via COM Interop = "The requested operation requires delegation to be enabled on the machine."

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, com-interop, rsa

So i've got this little static method in a .Net class which takes a string, uses some stored public key and returns the encrypted version of that key.  This is basically so some user entered data can be saved an encrypted, then retrieved and decrypted at a later date.  Pretty basic stuff and the unit test works fine.

However, part of the application is in classic ASP.  This then uses some COM visible version of the class to go off and invoke the method on the real class and return the same string to the COM client (classic ASP).  I use this kind of stuff all the time, but in this case we have a major problem.  As the method is doing something with RSA keys and has to access certain machine information to do so, we get the error:

"The requested operation requires delegation to be enabled on the machine.

I've searched around a lot, but can't really understand what this means. I assume I am getting this error on the COM but not the UT because the UT runs as me (Administrator) and classic ASP as IWAM.  Anyone know what I need to do to enable IWAM to do this? Or indeed if this is the real problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/XP/Q_23577627.html) which might point you in the right direction. (Scroll to page bottom)

If you search with google:

> The requested operation requires
>   delegation to be enabled on the
>   machine

then select the second link you'll see the solution on the bottom.

Anyway, the solution said:

> Open Active Directory Users and
>   Computers. Find the name of the file
>   server, right-click on it and hit
>   properties. Go to the Delegation tab
>   and select "Trust this computer for
>   delegation to specified services only"
>   and choose Protected Storage and
>   Common Internet File System.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reponse.  I'm not signed up to expertsexchange, are you able to post the relevant snippet?

Answer (score 0):

From Sani's post:

> Open Active Directory Users and Computers. Find the name of the file server, right-click on it and hit properties. Go to the Delegation tab and select "Trust this computer for delegation to specified services only" and choose Protected Storage and Common Internet File System.

I would also check out [Remote Decryption on File Shares](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx#EFAA).  This has some details about Using Encrypting File System